# Fetching data from the network during onCreate -> onHandleIntent

Tags: android, networking, android-lifecycle, oncreate

I have a `onCreate` which will call `onHandleIntent`

In `onHandleIntent` I would like to to get something from a remote server and return the value from `onHandleIntent` to `onCreate`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you asking about an `Activity`?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's unclear what you're asking about - I'll assume it's about an `Activity`, in which case,

### You shouldn't do this!

From [official Android training materials](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html):

> *To avoid creating an unresponsive UI, **don't perform network operations on the UI thread**. By default, Android 3.0 (API level 11) and higher requires you to perform network operations on a thread other than the main UI thread; if you don't, a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is thrown.*

What you are asking involves running a network operation on the UI thread, which will almost certainly cause your app to crash.

There are other ways to get this effect, including asynchronous calls, placeholders (in case of images), using a local DB (+preloading), and so on. There are also libraries that help you do this (e.g. [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) for images).